# Rails 3.2. Routing helper generates unvalid links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In routes.rb:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|de/ do
    get 'service' => 'service#index'
    get 'service/:id' => 'service#show'
end
```

Then in view I use helper `service_path(params[:locale], id)` and get this link `/en/service.1`. 
But i need link like this `/en/service/1`.

Check the routing via `rake routes`:

```
service GET    (/:locale)/service(.:format)   service#index (locale=>/en|ru/}
        GET    (/:locale)/service/:id(.:format)  service#show {:locale=>/en|ru/}
```

How to get normal links like `/en/service/1`, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename your controller to pluralize form `Services`

Change in routes:

`get 'service' => 'service#index'` to `get 'services' => 'services#index', :as => :services`

and

get `'service/:id' => 'service#show'` to get `'services/:id' => 'services#show', :as => :service`

Or you can write simple:

```
resources :services, :only => [:show, :index]
```